# ReactJS update state on XHR callback

Tags: reactjs

I have a functional react component. I cant update state inside the callback. Outside works fine.

```
function GetBookingForWeek(weekNumber: number) {
        var xhttpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttpreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                setSelectedWeek("52"); // THIS DOESNT WORK untill i refresh the page
            }
        };
        xhttpreq.responseType = 'json';
        xhttpreq.open("GET", rooturl + '/api/booking/getbookings/?weekNumber=27', true);
        xhttpreq.send(null);
        setShowSpinner(true);
}
```

The existing questions have no solution. Just a long explaination of how React works.
I came from AngularJS (1.7), but I find ReactJS frustrating and not much improvement on AngularJS.

edit:

```
const [selectedWeek, setSelectedWeek] = useState(21);
```

Comment: Where/how is `setSelectedWeek` defined? What does it do? Where is this function defined in relation to the component?

Comment: edited main post

Answer (score 0):

Forget it. I am switching back to Angular.
What a time waste.
Frontend development is going backwards.